# Parsing Status JSON from Twitter using Python to find statuses count

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

I am using Tweepy to get all tweets made by @UserName. This is the following code

```
import urllib, json
import sys
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler

def twitter_fetch(screen_name = "prateek",maxnumtweets=10):

consumer_token = "" #Keys removed for security
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_secret = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_token,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_secret)

api  = tweepy.API(auth)

for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,id=screen_name).items(1):
    print status['statuses_count']
    print '\n'



if __name__ == '__main__':
twitter_fetch('BarackObama',200)
```

How do I parse the JSON properly to read the Number of statuses made by that particular user ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to post the JSON output from your query, maybe on pastebin?

Comment: @SamCyanide
http://pastebin.com/C1RiGUtF - absolutely untouched output

Comment: So you want to count the total number of tweets made by a particular person ? is that all you are looking for ? There is no need to iterate over something , it would be as easy as writing a simple line of code and tweepy will do all the work for you. Tell me if you were also looking for the same

Answer (score 1):

How about something that keeps track of how many statuses you've iterated through? I'm not positive how tweepy works, but using something like this:

```
statuses = 0
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,id=screen_name).items(1):
    print status['statuses_count']
    statuses += 1
    print '\n'
return statuses
```

Usually JSON data has a nice structure, with clear formatting like the following, making it easier to understand.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/apLWCh5.png]

So when I want to iterate through this list to find if an x exists (achievement, in this case), I use this function, which adds 1 to index every iteration it goes through.

```
def achnamefdr(appid,mykey,steamid64,achname):
    playerachurl = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetPlayerAchievements/v0001/?appid=' + str(appid) + '&key=' + mykey + '&steamid=' + steamid64 + '&l=name'

    achjson = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(playerachurl).read().decode('utf-8'))

    achjsonr = achjson['playerstats']['achievements']

    index = 0
    for ach in achjsonr:
        if not ach['name'].lower() == achname.lower():
            index += 1
            continue
        else:
            achnamef = ach['name']
            return achnamef, index, True
    return 'Invalid Achievement!', index, False
```

Comment: for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,id=screen_name).items(1)

this line iterates the loop as many times as the number which is given as a param to items(). I thot - maybe we just read one tweet/status in jSON Format we get the number of tweets he has made in his Lifetime. We then use that number to iterate through the loop, giving the number of statuses as the parameter to items()

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by getting the JSON object from **status._json** and then parsing it..

```
print status._json["statuses_count"]
```